# Winforms: Wait Cursor with info-text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cursor

Is there a possibility to show a small infotext beside a wait-cursor. This would be a nice feature, to give some activity information to the user, during he/she is waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You must use a label next to the mouse position. just try following codes :

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            Label lb = new Label();
            lb.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X-this.Left,MousePosition.Y-this.Top);
            lb.Text = "Your Info";
            this.Controls.Add(lb);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use custom cursor. [C# Tutorial - How To Use Custom Cursors](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors)